# Data Protection in EU for usage of personal documents

Tags: compliance, privacy

I don't know if this question fits into this forum or not.
Is there some template documents that comply with the EU regulations for Data Protection and Privacy that I can reuse / (get them signed by the data subject) in order to collect some their personal related data?

The idea is that I will pass over these templates to the persons I would collecting personal data from mentioning the purpose and etc and then they sign it.

I was trying to prepare something from my knowledge but it turns out that even some of the basic questions I am not able to answer. e.g. should the data subject only sign this form or me as well? should i give him a copy? Is the electronic form fine (email) or should i get it on paper?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info - where are you, and where are your customers (data subjects)? I'll pop up some examples but it will depend a lot on locations.

Comment: I am in Germany and the data subjects are any person I meet in a public security conference and the info collected will remain for the purpose of helping my colleagues that couldn't join the conference so never public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really good set of examples in Ireland are at http://www.dataprotection.ie/viewdoc.asp?DocID=38. This site provides templates and describes the contract issues that may need to be tackled (your particular country may have a slightly different flavour):

- Adherence to data protection rules
- Transparency
- Cooperation
- Liability

[This copy of the Directive](http://www.cdt.org/privacy/eudirective/EU_Directive_.html) also gives good guidance, but unfortunately does not provide templates.